# Can White Walkers raise the giants from dead and convert into wights (army of dead)?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Not sure which season (probably 1st), I have seen a white walker riding on a dead horse, so we can safely assume the White Walkers can raise dead animals also.

However, what about the giants? I am thinking about this scenario: giant fighting along (alive) humans and got killed by wights or a White Walker. After this happens can he be raised and fight for the other side?

Reference from books is also fine.

Comment: Just to specify: what you saw was a White Walker riding a dead horse. According to what was shown so far wights don't ride. Answer to [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/white-walkers-vs-army-of-the-dead) explains the difference between White Walkers and wights.

Comment: I believe in season 1 on or somewhere else. I will search and share the video from youtube.

Comment: Yes, it was white walker riding undead horse. I am clear about difference between them, its just i remembers it wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [GoT Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wights#In_the_books):

> In the A Song of Ice and Fire novels, the Others (the book term for
>   the White Walkers) are able to animate corpses, human and animals
>   alike, to serve them as footmen or mounts. According to old records,
>   the Others are capable of reviving any dead animal as a wight, such as
>   horses, dogs, bears, direwolves, mammoths, giants, ice spiders and
>   even aquatic animals.

The giants were listed among animals in these "old records", because [in the books](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Giants#In_the_books) they are much more animalistic in appearance.

Comment: so... there are non-undead "normal" ice spiders? "Oh no, Cuddles my friendly pet ice spider has been re-animated as a monstrous *undead* ice spider!"

Comment: @user568458  One of my favorite lines from Ygritte is when she tells Jon Snow, "Oh, a spider! Save me, Jon Snow!" -because of  reference to not yet seen giant undead ice spiders that book readers would know of! :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can, Spoilers from season 7 ahead:

This is what we see in Bran's vision :

> [image]
>  
> and he might be/most probably Wun Wun turned into a wight. How the White Walkers got his body from the south of the wall is not made clear yet or if he is really Wun Wun or some other random giant.

But that does prove that White Walkers can raise the giants from dead and convert into wights.

From S07E06:

> they even raised a dragon from dead ([which I covered in this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78951/1190)), so a Giant seems not so tough.

Comment: That is **not Wun Wun**. Wun Wun was in Winterfell. Those are members of Wun Wun's family (there is more than one giant in that vision).

Comment: @GhotiandChips you mean a giant who look exactly like Wun Wun and have similar injuries but still not Wun Wun? And did you forgot Bran can see future visions too.

Comment: Yes, I do mean that the giant who died in Winterfell, right next to the man who says "We need to burn the body" the most times in the entire series, did not wake up as a wight, go over the wall and join the army of the Dead. The giant in the vision is one of many who died a while back - don't forget the giants only joined the wildling army under Mance Rayder because they were among the last of the giants, and had seen the dead.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I still think it's Wun Wun and who said bran was seeing present not future? They can cross wall too. Anyway updated answer

Comment: And if you wanted tangible evidence, [Ramsay shoots Wun Wun in the right eye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QACt2jqXRKU), which would conflict with the appearance of this other giant in the vision. it was a nice attempt, Ankit, but no dice.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Don't know if you got the point or not but the question is not if he is Wun Wun or not but can they revive giants or not.

Comment: Don't know if you got the point or not, but the comment I made was correcting your false claim in your answer that said it's Wun Wun in the scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63973/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-ghoti-and-chips).

Comment: Let's not. I made my point, which is that **that is not Wun Wun**, everything else is just me replying to you disagreeing with more valid points that reinforce my point. Nothing more has to be said. You can continue to believe it's Wun Wun, if you like, it's not my concern, but claiming it falsely in an answer deserves a comment like mine clarifying that it's false. :)